# How can I reset all system file permissions in Debian 10?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

I want to reset all system file permissions. Because I used `sudo chmod 777 -R /` command. But I don't know how.

Comment: You need to recover them from backup.

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't want to fix problem. I want to reset all system file permissions.

Comment: @Programmer the only way to "fix the problem" would be to "reset all system file permissions". It's probably not worth the effort and it will be easier and faster to reinstall but read the answers of the duplicate for more details.

Comment: I don't grok you. You say I don't want to fix it, I want to reset it. What is resetting? What do you want to reset them to?